# Inconsistent classification of individuals in Protege 4.3

Tags: owl, protege

I have been studying Protege and I have a question. I added an individual with name **aaa** in ontology "[people.owl](http://owl.man.ac.uk/2006/07/sssw/people.owl)" which I downloaded from the internet.

I set type assertion as:
    **sheep and hasCC value 200**,
where **hasCC** is data property.
Then, in class animal I created two classes: **hhh** and **lll**.
I set **hhh** as equivalent and there wrote:
    **animal and (hasCC some decimal[>= 150])**
For **lll** I set:
    **animal and (hasCC some decimal[< 250])**

When I run HermiT reasoner I see that the individual **aaa** is classified in both **lll** and **hhh** classes.
But when I set **lll** and **hhh** classes to be disjoint and run the reasoner the classes are not classified in the class "**Nothing**" as, for example, the class "**mad_cow**". I get a message:
"Your ontology is inconsistent which means that the OWL reasoner will no longer be able to provide any useful information about the ontology." After clicking the button "Explain" I get:

[image: Inconsistent ontology explanation]

Could you say, why **lll** and **hhh** classes cannot be classified as **Nothing**?
What should I correct to let **lll** and **hhh** classes to be classified as **Nothing**?
Thank you!

Comment: I don't get it. Why do you want something to be "classified" as Nothing?

Comment: I am writing a Python program and using library owlready2. The program will determine some individuals and then classify them. It would be good if some "wrong" classes with "wrong" individuals were classified as inconsistent. For example, all parameters of a system (i mean individuals with a few data properties) indicate that a gate valve is closed. It means all individuals will be classified in a class "GateValve1Closed" and the class "GateValve1Open" will be empty.

Comment: But if somehow a system is changed and one of the data properties indicates that the gate valve is open while other indicate that the gate valve is closed. Then, the individual will be in both classes GateValve1Open and GateValve1Closed. I would like the classes to be classified as Nothing. I just wrote simple example in my previous question to demonstrate the error which I got. I have no idea why whole ontology becomes inconsistent if i make like i wrote above.

Answer (score 0):

> "Your ontology is inconsistent which means that the OWL reasoner will no longer be able to provide any useful information about the ontology."

Isn't this saying it all already? You complain that the reasoner is not doing something but the reasoner explicitly tells you that it is not able to provide any useful information! Make your ontology consistent, then you can expect something from the reasoner.

In any case, you cannot expect a class that contains an instance (here the classes `hhh` and `lll` both must contain instance `aaa`) to be equivalent to `Nothing`. `Nothing` precisely means "the class that does not have any instance".

Comment: But why does the reasoner make the whole ontology inconsistent? I just managed to do the same thing with pizza ontology. For example, I made a class NOTSpicyTopping equivalent to "PizzaTopping and (hasSpiciness some Mild)". Then I made a class NOTSpicyPizza equivalent to "Pizza and (hasTopping some NOTSpicyTopping)". Then, I disjoint the class NOTSpicyPizza with SpicyPizza. After that **only** AmericanHot, Cajun, PolloAdAstra, SloppyGiuseppe were classified as **Nothing!** But if I make the above mentioned example, then the whole ontology becomes inconsistent. Maybe I do something wrong?

Comment: @Vladimir you asked why the two classes cannot be classified as subclasses of owl:Nothing. They cannot because they are not; the intersection of these two classes is owl:Nothing, but the classes separately are not unsatisfiable. The only issue with the ontology is that there is an individual assigned to both.

Comment: Thank you for your answers. It seems it is impossible to make what i want